Cloned HDD to SSD "no media present"
I recently used a StarTech USB 3.0/eSATA 1:1 SATA Duplicator Dock with UASP Part# SDOCK2U33RE
to clone a mirrored pair of 500GB 2.5in Seagate HDD's to 500GB Samsung SSD 870 EVO's and it worked without an issue.
I then attempted this again for another identical PC with identical drives and the new SSD's would not boot. I have connected the drives to my PC to check them with windows disk management and everything appears fine. When going to properties under the volumes tab the disks read as GPT for the boot.
During my research I saw someone suggest setting the drive to active using diskpart in the windows terminal. I attempted this and received the error "The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks."
Please if anyone has any ideas as to why this clone failed let me know.

Active is more a factor in older drives and OSes. Did you try duplicating again, just in case there was an error in the previous one?
